# Designing command that prevents \hline in a tabular?

Tags: tables, rules

I am trying to design a custom `tabular`-like environment with (among others) the following features:
 - there is an automatic `\hline` between all tabular rows;
 - the user is provided with a command, say `\nohline`, that when input *at the beginning* of a row, prevents the above `\hline` from being input.

So for example

```
\begin{mytabular}
a & b \\ c & d \\ \nohline e & f
\end{mytabular}
```

should be equivalent to

```
\begin{tabular}
\hline a & b \\ \hline c & d \\ e & f
\end{tabular}
```

(Note that I really want the macro `\nohline` to operate in this way, for reasons that are not to be discussed here - essentially: compatibility with already-written code, and substituability of stylesheets. Also, I know that this is hard to do, which is why I come to TeX.SX in the first place - if it were only a matter of “use such and such packages” then I could manage myself! So please, if all you can say is “I don't like this question”, then move on to the next one. Thanks.)

I tried playing a bit with `\noalign` and `\everycr`: my basic idea was something like

```
\def\everycr{\futurelet\token\oneline}
\def\oneline{\ifx\token\nohline\else\hline\fi}
\def\nohline{}
```

The problem with this is that the `\noalign` (found in the expansion of `\hline`) must immediately follow `\cr` *at the lexical level*, thus the `\futurelet` is not discarded and this raises a “misplaced `\noalign`” error.

Is there any other way to make the contents of the `\noalign{`...`}` block depend on the presence of the `\nohline` macro?

Comment: That's not a good design to do and undo successively. Instead you should not do anything by default and make things on demand including drawing every row. For example having a counter and checking whether given numbers match the row number etc.

Comment: Making a very easy task automatic by hard means and working on a more hard solution to drop out of the automation. Just leave it. A good table has a few lines as possible.

Comment: Which TeX engine do you use -- pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX?

Comment: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012). (I know it's old, but I am not the sysadmin). I think there is a LuaTeX inside this, however I'm not familiar at all with this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of doing it using the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\let\realarraycr\@arraycr% save original
\newcommand\mytabularnewline{\realarraycr\myhline\global\let\myhline\hline}
\newcommand\nohline{\global\let\myhline\relax}% \myhline does nothing
\newenvironment{mytabular}[1]{%
   \let\@arraycr\mytabularnewline% hijack \@arraycr
   \let\myhline\hline% 
   \tabular{#1}\myhline% start a tabular environment
   }{\endtabular}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{mytabular}{cc}
    a & b \\  \nohline c & d \\ e & f \\
  \end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

The `array` package calls `\@arrayr` at the end of each row of a `tabular`, or `array`, environment. The idea is to hijack `\@arraycr` and change it so that `\myhline` is used at the end of each line. By default, `\myhline` is the same as `\hline` but `\nohline` changes it to `\relax`.

Here's the output:

[image]

As I am using a `tabular` environment behind the scenes the `mytabular` environment takes an argument which specifies the number of columns and their alignment.

It is probably no harder doing something similar without loading the `array` package.

Comment: This seems cleaner than my solution (which is, however, now implemented in production, and seems to work fine so far). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. One solution (dirty) is to:

- first scan for tokens at beginning of line,
- once this is done, if we must draw a `\hline`, then we reissue a new `\cr` to return to beginning of line, and add a new `\noalign` to insert some negative vertical glue to return to the previous position (I think that `-\normalbaselineskip` is the right amount here).

Here is a sample code that works for me. Note that since the `colortbl` package is loaded (I must have it), this makes a few slight changes: namely `\CT@everycr` replaces `\everycr`, and I must also preserve `\CT@row@color`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\fakenoalign#1{%
  \global\CT@everycr{}%
  \cr\noalign{\vskip-\normalbaselineskip}#1%
  \global\CT@everycr{\futurenonspacelet\token\oneline}%
}
\def\oneline{%
  \ifx\token\merge\relax\else
  \ifx\token\header\fakenoalign\toprule \else
  \ifx\token\end\fakenoalign{\bottomrule\noalign{\vskip-\normalbaselineskip}} 
  \else
  \fakenoalign\midrule\fi\fi\fi
\ignorespaces}
\def\makeunique#1{\def#1{\let#1#1\ignorespaces}\ignorespaces}

\newenvironment{tableau}{%
  \let\CT@row@color\relax
  \makeunique\header
  \makeunique\merge
  \global\CT@everycr{\futurenonspacelet\token\oneline}%
  \begin{tabular}%
}{\global\CT@everycr{}\end{tabular}%
  \CT@everycr{\noalign{\global\let\CT@row@color\relax}\the\everycr}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{tableau}{ll}
\header 1&2\\ a&b\\\merge c&d\\
\end{tableau}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule 1 & 2\\ \midrule a & b\\ c & d\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```